# hit is not Visible on a button in windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I am making a button with a item template but when I click on Button its does not show that whether it is hit or not.

I want that it should look clicked like normal button.

I tried to set the ishitvisible property of the button but its not working.

Can anyone help ??

```
 <Button Name="BtnSignUp" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnSignUp_Click" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="5,15,0,0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#866DA9">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#491776" IsHitTestVisible="True" >
                            <TextBlock Text="Sign Up Now -" Margin="35,5,0,0" FontSize="23" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" it's free" Margin="0,5,35,10" FontSize="23" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Normal" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Can you post the DataTemplate XAML here?

Comment: <Button Name="BtnSignUp" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnSignUp_Click" >
<Button.Template>
<ControlTemplate>
<Border Margin="5,15,0,0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#866DA9">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#491776" IsHitTestVisible="True" >
<TextBlock Text="Sign Up Now -" Margin="35,5,0,0" FontSize="23" FontWeight="Medium"/>
<TextBlock Text=" it's free" Margin="0,5,35,10" FontSize="23" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Normal" />
</StackPanel>
</Border>

</ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
</Button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you are not using Item Template. You override Control Template. So you cannot get the default pressed effects of button. But still you can add that using Visual State Managers or through triggers.

I have posted an example of how to adjust opacity on mouse over and pressed.

```
            <Button Name="BtnSignUp" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnSignUp_Click" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="5,15,0,0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#866DA9">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="bor" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#491776" IsHitTestVisible="True" >
                            <TextBlock Text="Sign Up Now -" Margin="35,5,0,0" FontSize="23" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" it's free" Margin="0,5,35,10" FontSize="23" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Normal" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bor" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="bor" Value="0.6"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Comment: basically this is not working properly for me but now i have changed my template to contenttemplate so now it is working fine... thanx for help XAML Lover ...